# select2: get the selected options on edit page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-select2

I am using select2 in a WordPress plugin. The basic purpose is to select the multiple values. I am able to select multiple values and save them in the database. The issue is on the edit page. It does not show the selected options. But in the view source mode, the selected options have selected attribute.

```
<select name="course_info_meta[campus_id][]" id="campus_id" 
class="regular-text select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <optgroup label="Multan College of Science">
  <option value="16"> Johar Campus </option>
  <option value="11" selected="selected"> MCH Boys Branch </option>
  <option value="13" selected="selected"> MCH Girls Branch </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup></optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Jalal Pur Public School">
  <option value="14"> Boys Campus </option>
  <option value="15" selected="selected"> JPPS Shuja Abad Campus </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup> </optgroup>
</select>
```

The jQuery is here

```
jQuery(function($) {
// Select2 dropdown for campuses
    $('#campus_id').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a Campus',             
    'multiple': true,
    closeOnSelect: false,
        });
   });
```

[image]

The php code

```
   public function getAllCampusesList() {

        $results = $this->getAllCampusesData();


         foreach ($results as $key => $school) {

            $school_name = $this->getSchoolNameById($key);

             echo "<optgroup label='".$school_name."'>";

             foreach ($school as $campus){

                 echo "<option value='".$campus['id']."' ".$this->selected_campus($campus['id'])."> ".$campus['name']." </option>";

             } //level_2

             echo "<optgroup>";

         } //level_1

}   

 private function getAllCampusesData() {
    $transient = PMS_Management::PLUGIN_SLUG . '_campus_list';
    //delete_transient($transient);
    if ( false === ( $ret = get_transient( $transient ) ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $query = "SELECT id,slug FROM `{$wpdb->pms_schools}`";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query,ARRAY_A);
        $ret = array();
        if ( !empty( $results ) ):

            foreach ( $results as $row ):
                $slug = PMS_Management::PLUGIN_SLUG . '_' . $row['slug'];
                $args = array(
                        'orderby'       => 'date', 
                        'order'         => 'ASC',
                        'hide_empty'    => false, 
                        'fields'        => 'all', 
                        'hierarchical'  => false, 
                    );
                $terms = get_terms( $slug, $args );

                if( !is_wp_error( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ):
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $semester = array (
                            'id' => $term->term_id,
                            'name' => $term->name,
                            'slug' => $term->slug,
                        );
                        $ret[ $row['id'] ][ $term->term_id ] = $semester;

                    }
                endif;
            endforeach;

            set_transient( $transient, $ret, WEEK_IN_SECONDS );

            $transient_keys = get_option( 'my_transient_keys', array() );
            if( !array_key_exists($transient, $transient_keys) ) {
                $transient_keys[] = $transient;
                update_option( 'my_transient_keys', $transient_keys );
            }

        endif;

    }
   //echo "<pre>"; print_r($ret); echo '</pre>';        
    return $ret;
}//end of 



/* clone function for WordPress selected()
    ** It checkd either the option was selected or not
    */
    public function selected_campus($id){

    global $post;

    $get_ids = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_campus_id', true);

    $ids = json_decode($get_ids, true);

    if (in_array($id, $ids)){
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        return $selected;
    }//
```

Comment: Working for me https://jsfiddle.net/dxevaf3b/

Comment: Thanks @SanchitPatiyal. Can you please suggest where can be the issue?

Comment: Are you populating these options dynamically??

Comment: No, these values are retrieved from a custom dabase table

Comment: Can you show me the code where these values are retrieved??

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163067/discussion-between-zubair-mushtaq-and-sanchit-patiyal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since option are being set dynamically. It'll only make last item as selected in the list of selected items. Instead you need to update it like this -

```
 $("#campus_id").val(["MCH Boys Branch","MCH Girls Branch","JPPS Shuja Abad Campus"]).trigger("change")
```